# Can not get @Controller to import package

Tags: java, spring

In my main Controller file, I can not get the annotation @Controller to import and clear the error. I just get "Controller is not an annotation type" which is really confusing.

```
@Controller
public class Controller {
    
}
```

Comment: Well, don't name your class `Controller`... You just shot yourself in the foot.

Comment: What dependency did you include in your project which should contain that annotation?

Comment: The @Controller is above the public class.

Comment: I checked the POM.XML file first, I thought I was lacking a dependency.

Comment: BE gentle guys, I just started Spring and have only dabbled with JS and Python..

Answer (score 3):

Try renaming the class like below:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller 
public class MainController {


}
```

Comment: package com.edmundo.routingpractice3.codeofhonor;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class Controllers {
 
 @RequestMapping("/")
 String testing = "This is a test route.";

}

Comment: This worked but now I can not place the Annotation @RequestMapping inside..

Comment: I just figured it out:)

Comment: @EdmundoRuiz don't name your class `Controllers` either. An instance of that class is a single controller. There is no reason to use the plural form here. Choose a **good**, descriptive name for the class. What does this controller deal with? Does it deal with, for example, your home page? The name it `HomeController`.

Answer (score -1):

@RestController is more used than Controller. It is imported from org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;